# Cannot read property 'data' of undefined on a not-even started $http.get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a web application, started by a previous company, written in Angular.JS. 
The application exposes a request towards the back-end (written in Node.JS+Express) to gather some data required to fill a table. 
Specifically, this is the request that the application sends everytime the user enters in the page that holds the table (The config variable holds the access token).

```
define(['app'], function (app) {

    app.factory('AdvService', AdvService);

    AdvService.$inject = ['BasicService'];
    function AdvService(BasicService) {

      var service = angular.extend(BasicService, {});
      var $http = service.$http;
      var API = service.API
      var handleSuccess = service.handleSuccess;
      var handleError = service.handleError;
      var config = {
        params: {
            'token': JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('session')).token
        }
      };

      service.searchByCriteria = function (criteria) {
        debugger;
        config.params.pageNumber = criteria.pageNumber;
        config.params.pageSize = criteria.pageSize;
        return $http.get(API + '/api/v2/admin/ads/getAdsByCriteria', config).then(handleSuccess, handleError);  
      };

      service.createAd = function (ad) {
        debugger;
        return $http.post(API + '/api/v2/admin/ads/insertNewAd', ad, config).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
      };

      return service;      
    }

});
```

handleSuccess and handleError are so defined

```
define(['app'], function (app) {

    app.factory('BasicService', BasicService);

    BasicService.$inject = ['CONF', '$http', '$window', '$q'];
    function BasicService(CONF, $http, $window, $q) {

        $http.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token'] = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem('session')).token;

        return {
            $http: $http,
            API: CONF.API_URL,

            handleSuccess: function (res) {
                debugger;
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                res.data.success ? deferred.resolve(res.data) : deferred.reject(res.data.message);
                return res.data;
            },

            handleError: function (error) {
                debugger;
                return {
                    success: false,
                    message: error
                };
            }
        }

    }
})
```

and this is the only point of the application that calls that service

```
    ($scope.search = function () {
        debugger;
        AdvService.searchByCriteria($scope.searchCriteria).then(function (res) {
            debugger;
            $scope.searchRes = res.data.docs;
            //$scope.gridOptions.totalItems = res.data.total;
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    })();
```

Being a CORS request (the front-end is at port 8010 and the back-end in another one), I see from Chrome's Network Monitoring System that the $http.get part gets executed twice, but here's my problem: even before starting handling on the back-end the first call, the front-end generates the error

```
angular.js:14961 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (ui-grid.js:3291)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5117)
    at $controllerInit (angular.js:11139)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:10002)
    at angular.js:10410
    at processQueue (angular.js:17330)
    at angular.js:17378
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18515)
    at Scope.scopePrototype.$digest (hint.js:1495)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18903)
```

and even tough the request does return data, having crashed, Angular cannot correctly render everything. 
The only thing I tried was to use the Await/Async mechanism to try to wait and see what could have happened but this always resolves in the above error.

Does anybody have any clue of what's going on? I'm 100% positive that the code that I've posted here is the only one that gets called during this process and I can't honestly understand why should the process fail if both requests return data

Comment: Just for the testing - Try changing `return deferred.promise;` to `return res.data;` (Without the promise logic) and also I think that `res.data.docs` should be `res.docs` and so for the next line, because you returning the response body from the `handleSuccess` function

Comment: @AlonEitan Still have the same problem

Comment: And what happens when you comment this line: `$scope.gridOptions.totalItems = res.data.total;` ?

Comment: The error pops up even before the debugger reaches that line of code. Actually, it appears right after the debugger goes after the line of the $http.get BUT, on the back-end, the endpoint still hasn't started processing the request

Comment: OK. So I see that `handleSuccess` and `handleError` are a part of some object - so shouldn't you bind those to the `$http` callback using `myObj.handleSuccess` and `myObj.handleError`? Of course `myObj` is just a random name that I picked, you should use the name of the variable that hold those functions

Comment: @AlonEitan I've updated the question by adding how the services are defined

Comment: It looks like it comes from `uiGrid`- This is the [line](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/ui-grid.js) I'm suspecting `if (angular.isString($scope.uiGrid.data)) {` but if that is the case then I don't know what the error might be related to how you're binding the data to the grid.

Comment: @AlonEitan I've tried to comment the 'data' part of the grid but the problem still persist :(

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm out of ideas. I think the issue is not the request itself but the way you're binding the data to the grid.

Comment: @AlonEitan you think so? Consider I've just copied and pasted (and adapted) this code from other controllers that have the same grid mechanisms and it works :(

Comment: I do, because look at the error `at Object.<anonymous> (ui-grid.js:3291)` - Note that `ui.grid` is somehow related to this

Comment: Well I was able to [reproduce](http://plnkr.co/edit/P9tIwY5w6ebswwYEbQ88?p=preview) the same error on the same line (`ui-grid.js:3291`) - Note that I bind the grid in the view like this: `ui-grid="gridOptionsERROR"`, now if you remove the `ERROR` it will work. Maybe you didn't bind the correct options for the `uiGrid` directive in your view?

Comment: @AlonEitan *face palm* yes, that was it! If you make it an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: I don't know how it was before and after on your side, so you can self-answer your question explaining how you solved it. Glad I was able to help. Eventually ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as correctly pointed out by Alon Eitan in the comments, the error was somehow related with ui-grid and that, probably, it might have been that the gridOptions were not correctly called like the HTML was excepting.

 **IN FACT** ...

HTML

```
<div class="alerts container-fluid" ng-controller="AdsController">
        <div class="row">
            WORK IN PROGRESS!
            <!--  <span>Pubblicità attive: <b>{{activeAdsCounter}}</b> - </span>-->
            <!-- <span>Pubblicità totali: <b>{{totalAdsCounter}}</b> - </span>-->
        </div>
        <button ng-click="openCreateNewAdModal()"><i class="material-icons">library_add</i></button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Pubblicità Nel Sistema</h3>
                <div class="grid" ui-grid="adsGridOptions" ui-grid-pagination
                    ui-grid-auto-resize></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
define(['app', 'moment'], function (app, moment) {

    app.controller('AdsController', AdsController);
    AdsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$mdDialog', 'AdvService'];

    function AdsController($scope, $mdDialog, AdvService) {
        debugger;
        $scope.rowHeight = 30;
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'searchRes',
            paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
            paginationPageSize: 25,
            enableSorting: true,
            enablePaginationControls: true,
            enableColumnMenus: false,
            useExternalPagination: true,
            rowHeight: $scope.rowHeight,
            columnDefs: [
                 {
                    name: 'Cliente',
                    field: 'customerName',
                }, {
                    name: 'Durata',
                    field: 'duration',
                },  {
                    name: 'Euro Spesi',
                    field: 'spentEuros',
                },  {
                    name: 'Data inserimento',
                    field: 'createdAt',
                    type: 'date',
                    width: '130',
                    cellFilter: "date:'dd-MM-yyyy'",
                },  {
                    name: 'Email Referente',
                    field: 'referralEmail',
                },  {
                    name: 'Nome Referente',
                    field: 'referralPerson',
                },  {
                    name: 'Numero Referente',
                    field: 'referralNumber',
                },
            ],
            onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function (grid, sortColumns) {
                    if (sortColumns[0]) {
                        console.log(sortColumns[0].sort);
                        $scope.searchCriteria.sort = {};
                        $scope.searchCriteria.sort[sortColumns[0].field] = sortColumns[0].sort.direction;
                    }
                });
                $scope.gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (pageNum, pageSize) {
                    $scope.searchCriteria.pageNumber = pageNum;
                    $scope.searchCriteria.pageSize = pageSize;
                    $scope.search();
                });
            }
        };
```

The controller had the options called as "gridOptions", while the HTML had them called "adsGridOptions". Changing the name to "gridOptions" to both sides solved the issue.

Thank you, Alon Eitan!